# When are custom TableCatalogs loaded?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've created a custom Catalog in Spark 3.0.0:
`class ExCatalogPlugin extends SupportsNamespaces with TableCatalog`

I've provided the configuration asking Spark to load the Catalog:
`.config("spark.sql.catalog.ex", "com.test.ExCatalogPlugin")`

But Spark never loads the plugin, during debug no breakpoints are ever hit inside the `initialize` method, and none of the namespaces it exposes are recognized.  There are also no error messages logged.  If I change the class name to an invalid class name no errors are thrown either.

I wrote a small TEST case similar to the test cases in the Spark code, and I am able to load the plugin if I call:

```scala
package org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog
....
class CatalogsTest extends FunSuite {
    test("EX") {
        val conf = new SQLConf()
        conf.setConfString("spark.sql.catalog.ex", "com.test.ExCatalogPlugin")
        val plugin:CatalogPlugin = Catalogs.load("ex", conf)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark is using it's normal *Lazy* loading techniques, and doesn't instantiate the custom Catalog Plugin until it's needed.

In my case referencing the plugin in one of two ways worked:

- `USE ex`, this explicit USE statement caused Spark to lookup the catalog and instantiate it.
- I have a companion `TableProvider` defined as `class DefaultSource extends SupportsCatalogOptions`.  This class has a hard coded `extractCatalog` set to `ex`.  If I create a reader for this source, it sees the name of the catalog provider and will instantiate it. It then uses the Catalog Provider to create the table.